# How to import album into Music without hiccups between songs

Tags: itunes, music, music.app, encoding, m4a

I have recorded a concept album in which the tracks all run together. There are no pauses between songs. My mastering engineer has delivered 44.1khz/24-bit WAV files. I imported these into ProTools and confirmed that they fit perfectly and seamlessly together.

I imported the WAV files into Music on my Macbook. The files appear to play correctly in the Music app, and the transitions from one song to the next are seamless. If I <kbd>CTRL</kbd> - Click a song and select 'Show in Finder', I see that the song files exist as WAV files in my iTunes Music library.

HOWEVER, when I sync my iPhone, and the files are copied to my phone, there is a hiccup between songs for some reason -- a split second glitch between songs that interrupts the smooth flow. This is annoying AF and I want to eliminate these hiccups when playing my songs on my iPhone. I want to solve this problem not just in my case -- I want to be sure that my music, if downloaded by others, either via Dropbox or Google Drive or Apple or Bandcamp (or any other source) will play properly on one's phone.

I *suspect*, but am not sure, that the problem might be introduced by my iPhone sync settings. On the General tab of the sync settings, I have selected:

> ☑️ Convert higher bitrate songs to [256 kbps AAC]

I believe that this conversion is what has introduced the song hiccups in my case. Rather than turning this setting off -- which would make my music balloon to nearly a GB of data -- I'd prefer to offer MP3 or M4A files which won't suffer from these hiccups. Can someone tell me how to convert my WAV files to AAC or Apple lossless *without* these hiccups? 256kbps seems like a pretty hi-res file to me, and is the highest option available in the iphone sync options. I don't see any additional options in the iphone sync like 'no gap encoding' or whatever.

In what compressed format can I offer my music files to avoid these gaps/hiccups between songs? Can anyone recommend a file format and/or conversion workflow where I can insure a proper experience for my music? I would note here that I downloaded *Dark Side of the Moon* from iTunes some time ago and it does not suffer from these hiccups in my phone. I'd also note that the DSotM audio files in my iTunes library are M4A. The first track, *Speak to Me*, is 1m 5s long, with sample rate 44.1khz, and is only 2.9MB on disk so it is clearly compressed -- A stereo, 16-bit uncompressed file at this sampling rate would be about 10MB.

Note: I have already created WAV/MP3 versions of the entire album sides, one for each side, but I want to prepare the individual tracks for digital distribution -- via iTunes, Bandcamp, whatever.

Comment: There used to be a checkbox in iTunes to set gapless playback - unfortunately, someone decided we didn't need it any more. Even timeless classics like Dark Side of the Moon now have obnoxious gaps [tiny, but irritating. No longer seamless] :\

Comment: @Tetsujin NOOOOOO you have to be joking??

Comment: I tend to just shuffle everything in the car these days, so it hasn't bothered me greatly, but yeah, they dumped the gapless tag a few years ago. I have no clue why anyone thought that was a good idea. Just google 'itunes gapless' for a million complaints, apparently fallen on deaf ears.

Comment: If the idea is to listen to all the tracks in sequence, without skips, import them into Protools and merge them into _one single track_ that won't skip. You can keep the separate tracks for playback on your Macbook, and only sync the single-track version to your iPhone.

Comment: @IconDaemon I have already created WAV/MP3 versions of the entire album sides, one for each side, but I want to prepare the individual tracks for digital distribution -- via iTunes, Bandcamp, whatever.